# Desktop launcher and panel disabled (not visible) on VMware 10 Ubuntu 14

Tags: 14.04, windows-7, icons, taskbar, vmware-workstation

I installed Ubuntu 14.4 64 bit as guest OS on windows 7 using vmware workstation 10.

After installing I am not able to see the launcher (left) or panel (top).

Answer (score 3):

to solve the issue :

In Workstation right click on the VM (Ubuntu) then **Settings > Display** and in the right window, disable the **Accelerate 3D graphics** option using the checkbox